# How do I send email using java6?

Tags: java-6

There is some big chunk of code on old server(java 1.6.025). It builds sql query. It has too many dependencies with other classes, and I can't just take it out and test standalone.

So I decided to just run it AS-IS on server except **inject** some "send.Email()" code and just see what it does.

```
                sb.append("</key>");
            }
            sb.append("</" + st.tableName + ">");
            sb.append("</" + s + ">");
        }
        sb.append("</" + this.select.selectName + ">");
     //   XMLFunctions.addInfo("sb before os.write " + sb.toString());
        this.os.write(sb.toString().getBytes("utf-8"));
     //CODE HERE
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        XMLFunctions.addWarning((String)(String.valueOf(e.getClass().getCanonicalName()) + ": " + e.getMessage()));
    }
```

What code would work on java6?
EDIT: my class does not have main() where I can initialize email properties..

Comment: So you just want to know how to send an e-mail or how to inject the code or what exactly? Your question is not clear to me. Can you modify the old code  and recompile it for your test?

Comment: @xander, i want to inject the necessary code, and I dont have main() in this java class

Comment: If you are only concerned about initializing your email properties you sure have some method that is called at initialization and even if you don't you can always use a singleton class to only run the code once!?

Comment: mm not familiar with singleton

Comment: Just google "java singleton pattern", that's one of the simplest pattern you can use, essentially you can only have one object of a singleton class, like a static class.